# Meta tag descriptions

Tags: discussion

This is a Meta Meta question.

I just reviewed a number of tag guidance edits for several of the standard tags that are used on this meta site.  However, most of these tags like [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion), [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), etc. are not specific to Academia Meta, but have common meanings on Meta sites across the Stack Exchange system.  There are, in fact, technical requirements for how some of these tags are used on Meta sites and they have descriptions separate from the usual tag guidance found on main sites.

I voted not to approve most of the edits, since they did not agree with my understanding of how those tags are used on Meta sites; I tend to think there should be standardization for how, e.g., [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) is used, across the entire Stack Exchange platform.  However, I could not seem to find any rules (e.g. on the main Meta site) governing how tag guidance for common tags on Meta sites is meant to be used.  So I mostly just wanted to point this situation out here, so it can be discussed and dealt with if needed.